# Triple scalar product

Tags: vectors

So I came across this question: 
Given vector $\textbf{u} = i+j, \textbf{v} = j+k, \textbf{w} = i+k$. Find the triple scalar product $u(\textbf{v}\times \textbf{w})$.

So I tried to check my notes to see if I can solve it myself. And according to my notes, the triple scalar product of vectors $\textbf{u} = i+j+k, \textbf{v} = i+j+k \text{ and  } \textbf{w} = i+j+k$ is the determinant of the $3\times3$ matrix formed by the components of the vector.

If for my case I only have $2$ for each vector, does that mean the matrix is $2\times3$? I am kinda confused.

Comment: Maybe you can assume that the component which is left is zero.

Comment: So you mean 0, i and j for u, etc?

Comment: That would result in 0

Comment: It's not 0. The question was already answered under the same argument. Remember that $i$ is related to the $x-axis$, $j$ to the $y$ and $k$ to $z$.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

Those vectors should be interpreted as
\begin{align*}u &= 1\cdot\vec{i} + 1\cdot \vec{j}+ 0\cdot\vec{k}\\ v &= 0\cdot\vec{i} + 1\cdot \vec{j} + 1\cdot\vec{k}\\ w &= 1\cdot\vec{i} + 0\cdot \vec{j}+ 1\cdot\vec{k}\end{align*}
so that the coefficient matrix we'll be taking the determinant of is $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

The other components are always there, even if their coefficients are zero. These are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so we use coefficients with respect to the standard basis $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$, and that means all three coefficients to express any particular vector.

Comment: So i(jk-0)-j(0-ik)+0(0-ij), then 2ijk?

Comment: No. The scalar triple product is just a number. There is no generic product that we would ever write as "ijk".

Comment: So the answer should be a real number?